# I have followed the steps for turtlebot create base, but still it is showing failed to connect to /dev/kobuki?

Tags: turtlebot, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ROS indigo, I have followed the following steps for create base in turtlebot

> export TURTLEBOT_BASE=create
> export TURTLEBOT_STACKS=circles
> export TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR=kinect

But still whenever I enter the roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch

it shows the error

"Failed to open port /dev/kobuki.  Please make sure the Create cable is plugged into the computer.
"

Please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175249/i-have-followed-the-steps-for-turtlebot-create-base,-but-still-it-is-showing-failed-to-connect-to-/dev/kobuki-?/) by [vikiboy](https://answers.ros.org/users/19024/vikiboy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like there was an update in the turtlebot code: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/pull/112/files

Try setting TURTLEBOT_SERIAL_PORT to the device your create is listening to (probably /dev/ttyUSB0). I updated the [hydro wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/hydro/Create%20Base) to reflect this.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vikiboy](https://answers.ros.org/users/19024/vikiboy/) on 2014-06-29**:
The problem still persists with no change. is this specific to turtlebot in ros indigo ?

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-06-29**:
Hydro and indigo should be the same in this regard. Next step would be to check that there isn't a bug in the python create driver code. Add some printf's to make sure this parameter is getting through.

**Comment by [vikiboy](https://answers.ros.org/users/19024/vikiboy/) on 2014-06-30**:
It works now !! :D following this step